# BSNL WIMAX to WIFI

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, wimax

I have a bsnl wimax connection. Is it possible to have a wifi facility from this connection in order to share this internet connection with another PC and mobile phone and ipad . I tried to connect to a vmc an1201-21 adsl modem router but nothing happened. Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

You can create adhoc connection in windows & then anyone can connect to the network.